# xamarin forms zxing forms scanner crash

Tags: ios, xamarin, zxing

I'm using zxing.mobile.forms package for a scanner app I'm building. 
when code runs

```
var scannerPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
await Navigation.PushAsync(scannerPage);
```

The error reads: 
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.

The iPhone emulator exits the app to the home screen and theres no visible error message being displayed, just the output code above

Comment: Did you add the required entries in info.plist when asking for permissions?

Comment: which required entries? All that was required for iOS was placing a reference (ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();)  in appDelegate.cs

Comment: iOS 10 requires info.plist entries for permissions when using camera.

Comment: [Sim logs & crash reports](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/#debug-logs-for-xamarin-apps) may have clues. If [privacy keys](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios10/security-privacy-enhancements/#Accessing_Private_User_Data) are missing, the stacktrace may contain "CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION" as mentioned in the [release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.0/#Known_Issues).

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/421

Answer (score 0):

**Things To Try**

*Figuring Out The Error*

- Surround Your Method Action In Try Catch Braces
- In Visual Studio Go To Tools---> Options---> Xamarin ---> and set the Xamarin Diagnostics to Diagnostics

*Possible Quick Fix*

- Update Your Xamarin Form Nuget Package To The Latest & Greatest In Your PCL Project and iOS Project
- Un-installed The Previous Build From Your IOS Device & After Following The Step Above Re-Run

Comment: everything is up do date, diagnostics does not show anything

Comment: Make sure your MainPage is created in a navigation page.  Default template does not do this.  Bit me hard for 8 hours of my life.

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ZXingPlay.MainPage());